# R: Kruskal-Wallis test in loop over specified columns in data frame

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, statistics, kruskal-wallis

I would like to run a KW-test over certain numerical variables from a data.frame, using one grouping variable. I'd prefer to do this in a loop, instead of typing out all the tests, as they are many variables (more than in the example below).

**Simulated data:**

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
Data <- tbl_df(
data.frame(
muttype = as.factor(rep(c("missense", "frameshift", "nonsense"), each = 80)),
ados.tsc   = runif(240, 0, 10),
ados.sa    = runif(240, 0, 10),
ados.rrb   = runif(240, 0, 10))
) %>%
group_by(muttype)
ados.sim <- as.data.frame(Data)
```

**The following code works just fine outside of the loop.**

```
kruskal.test(formula (paste((colnames(ados.sim)[2]), "~ muttype")), data = 
ados.sim)
```

**But it doesn't inside the loop:**

```
for(i in names(ados.sim[,2:4])){  
ados.mtp <- kruskal.test(formula (paste((colnames(ados.sim)[i]), "~ muttype")), 
data = ados.sim)
}
```

**I get the error:**

*Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :
invalid term in model formula*

Anybody who knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
results <- list()
for(i in names(ados.sim[,2:4])){  
  results[[i]] <- kruskal.test(formula(paste(i, "~ muttype")), data = ados.sim)
}
```

This also saves your results in a list and avoids overwriting your results as `ados.mtp` in every iteration, which I think is not what you intended to do.

Note the following:

```
for(i in names(ados.sim[,2:4])){  
   print(i)
}
[1] "ados.tsc"
[1] "ados.sa"
[1] "ados.rrb"
```

That is, `i` already gives you the name of the column. The problem in your code was that you tried to use it like an integer for subsetting, which turned the outcome into `NA`.

```
for(i in names(ados.sim[,2:4])){  
   print(paste((colnames(ados.sim)[i]), "~ muttype"))
}
[1] "NA ~ muttype"
[1] "NA ~ muttype"
[1] "NA ~ muttype"
```

And just for reference, all of this could also be done in the following two ways that I often prefer since it makes subsequent analysis slightly easier:

First, store all test objects in a dataframe:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- ados.sim %>% gather(key, value, -muttype) %>% 
      group_by(key) %>% 
      do(test = kruskal.test(x= .$value, g = .$muttype))
```

You can then subset the dataframe to get the test outcomes:

```
df[df$key == "ados.rrb",]$test
[[1]]

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  .$value and .$muttype
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 2.2205, df = 2, p-value = 0.3295
```

Alternatively, get all results directly in a dataframe, without storing the test objects:

```
library(broom)
df2 <- ados.sim %>% gather(key, value, -muttype) %>% 
       group_by(key) %>% 
       do(tidy(kruskal.test(x= .$value, g = .$muttype)))
df2
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   key [3]
       key statistic   p.value parameter                       method
     <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <int>                       <fctr>
1 ados.rrb 2.2205031 0.3294761         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
2  ados.sa 0.1319554 0.9361517         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
3 ados.tsc 0.3618102 0.8345146         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
```

Comment: Many thanks! All options work and especially the last option is very neat!

Comment: Yeah, I think the combination of `dplyr::group_by` and `broom::tidy` is extremely handy when doing this sort of thing.

Comment: One additional question: In the case I have a very extensive dataframe, and I would want to take specific columns (not all except for "muttype"), how would I specify that in the latter two examples?

Comment: Have a look at `?gather`, which is the function that reshapes your dataframe. Alternatively, just add a `select` between `ados.sim` and `gather` where you include all columns that you will eventually need.

Comment: I think I have figured it out:

     df3 <- ados.sim %>% gather(key, value, **2:4**) %>% 

     group_by(key) %>% 

     do(tidy(kruskal.test(x= .$value, g = .$muttype)))

     df3

Answer (score 0):

If you can use external libraries:

```
library(matrixTests)

col_kruskalwallis(ados.sim[,-1], ados.sim[,1])

         obs.tot obs.groups df statistic    pvalue
ados.tsc     240          3  2 0.3618102 0.8345146
ados.sa      240          3  2 0.1319554 0.9361517
ados.rrb     240          3  2 2.2205031 0.3294761
```